# Using javascript to perform two actions on uploading a file. File and file details are not passed onto the javascript function

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

I am using this code to upload a file. I have to perform two submit actions. So I call a javascript function onclick(). However, neither the file nor the file details entered using the form are transferred to the javascript function. What am I missing here?

```html
<jsp:include page="template-top.jsp" />
<script type="text/javascript">
function onSubmit(){
    document.forms["frm"].action="http://192.168.1.53/api.php/submit.xml";
    document.forms["frm"].target="_blank";
    document.forms["frm"].submit();
    document.forms["frm"].action="directuploadsubmit.do";
    document.forms["frm"].target="_blank";
    document.forms["frm"].submit();
}
</script>
<style type="text/css">

td.boldtext{
font-weight: bold;
font-family:Helvetica,sans-serif;
font-size:16pt;
color:black;
width:200;
}

</style>
<%@ page import="databeans.Submit" %>
<%@ page import="databeans.User"  %>
<%@ page import="databeans.Sandboxes"  %>

<%
    User user = (User) session.getAttribute("user");
%>

<div style="visibility:hidden">
<iframe NAME = "iframe1" WIDTH="40" HEIGHT="40"></iframe>
</div>

<form id="frm" name="frm" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table>
    <tr> <td class="boldtext">
    Direct Submission
    </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table>
            <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
            <font color="red">Complete notes as Case#:Notes (Example: <font color="blue">"Case12345:test sample"</font>)
            </font>
            </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td width=50>
            <font color="black" face="Helvetica,sans-serif">File:* </font></td>
            <td><input type="file" name="file" value="${filename}" size="100"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td width=50>
            </td>
            <td><input type="hidden" name="email" readonly="readonly" value="<%=user.getUserName() %>" size="100"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td width=50>
            <font color="black" face="Helvetica,sans-serif">Notes: </font></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="notes" value="" size="100"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td width=50>
            <font color="black" face="Helvetica,sans-serif">Sandbox: </font></td>
            <td><select name="sandboxes[]">
            <option value="00-0C-29-CF-B8-A6">VMSB1 - Win7</option>
            <option value="00-0C-29-0A-AB-9A">VMSB2 - WinXP</option>
            </select>
            </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td width=50 colspan="2" align="left"><font face="Helvetica,sans-serif" color="FF0000">All * marked fields are mandatory    
            </font>
            </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td width=50 colspan="2" align="center">
        <!--    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" onclick= "this.form.target='_blank'; return true;">
        -->
        <input type="submit" name="button" value="Submit" onClick="onSubmit()">
            </td>
            </tr>
</table>
</form>
<jsp:include page="template-bottom.jsp" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should bind the `onSubmit` function to the form, instead of the `submit` button.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function onSubmit(){
    //First form submission:
    document.forms["frm"].action = "http://192.168.1.53/api.php/submit.xml";
    document.forms["frm"].submit(); //Submit #1

    //Change the action
    document.forms["frm"].action = "directuploadsubmit.do";
}
</script>
...

<form action="directuploadsubmit.do" onsubmit="onSubmit();" name="frm" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="_blank">
... rest of page
```

When the user has disabled JavaScript, the default action is to only submit the form to `directuploadsubmit.do`, in a new window. When JavaScript is enabled, the following happens:

1. The `action` attribute is changed, to `submit.xml`.
2. The form submits (using `.submit()`
3. The `action` attribute is changed (back to `direcuploadsubmit.do`
4. The form submits, because the user clicked at the submit button.<sup>[1]</sup>

<sup>[1]</sup> When an user clicks at submit, the following events occur:

1. The `submit` event is triggered (if JavaScript is enabled)
2. The form is submitted to the page as mentioned at `action`.

Comment: you were faster and your answer is better! =D Also, adding action="javascript:;" to the form may help

Comment: what do I do inside the javascript function between the two actions and submit? Should I be adding another "return false;" there?

Comment: Also if I add "return false;", I get an 'Cannot return from outside a function or method.' error

Comment: Eventhough Javascript is enabled and I have binded the onSubmit function to the form, the file is not being submitted through the api.php. But the form is being submitted to directuploadsubmit.do.
This is what I have:
<form id="frm" name="frm" action="directuploadsubmit.do" onSubmit="onSubmit();" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
.........
<input type="submit" name="button" value="Submit">
......
function onSubmit(){
 document.forms["frm"].action="http://192.168.1.53/api.php/submit.xml";
 document.forms["frm"].submit();
 document.forms["frm"].action="directuploadsubmit.do";
}

Answer (score 0):

you must prevent the default action of either the form or the submit button, by calling onclick="onSubmit(); return false;"

that won't let your form to get submited and allow you to handle the request beforehand